# Difference between SQL NOT IN and SQL EXCEPT, UNION and OR, AND and INTERSECT?

Tags: sql

On my rdbms these expressions give exactly the same output:

`select avd from avdelning where avd not in(select avd from försäljning) order by avd`

`select avd from avdelning except (select avd from försäljning) order by avd`

It seems that what you can write with SQL `EXCEPT` you can write with SQL `NOT IN` and likewise for `UNION` and `OR` and `AND` and `INTERSECT`. Could you tell me the differences between these keywords? For instance `select * from person where person not in (select * from person where name='foo')` is the same as `select * from person except where name='foo'` and similar for the other constructs. Are they really equivalent?

```
SELECT PersonId FROM person EXCEPT (SELECT PersonId FROM Addresses WHERE streetname='Elm Street')

=

SELECT PersonId FROM person WHERE PersonId NOT IN(SELECT PersonID FROM Addresses WHERE StreetName = 'Elm Street')
```

?

Comment: Your NOT IN example is not really very good. A better example would be something like: SELECT * FROM person WHERE PersonId NOT IN(SELECT PersonID FROM Addresses WHERE StreetName = 'Elm Street') which would give you a list of all people that don't live on Elm Street.

Comment: Voted to Close - This would be best asked on programmers.stackexchange.com - a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development.

Comment: There are frequently multiple ways to do things in SQL.  A lot of times it boils down to differences in flexibility, readability, and efficiency.

Comment: On my rdbms these expressions give exactly the same output:

`select avd from avdelning where avd not in(select avd from försäljning) order by avd`

`select avd from avdelning except (select avd from försäljning) order by avd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful:

http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/uploadfile/sscheral/sql-union-sql-intersect-sql-except-sql-exists-and-sql-case-for-beginners/

In practical terms I think one of the "differences" is that INTERSECT and EXCEPT aren't implemented across all platforms, (which is what I think Sung would suggest).